# Generate string variants based on list of lists of characters in python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I'd like to generate all possible string variants based on a list of lists of characters.

i.e. the input:

```
[['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['C']]
```

should yield:

```
['AABABC', 'ABDCBC', 'AABABC', 'ABDCBC', 'AABABC', 'ABDCBC', 'AABABC', 'ABDCBC']
```

The input is always 6 chars, for every char it can be either one or two variants.

I came up with the following solution:

```
import itertools


def levels(lst):
    nr_levels = 0
    for element in lst:
        if len(element) == 2:
            nr_levels += 1
    return nr_levels


def expand(data):
    results = []

    # calculate the number of results based on the "nesting" in the input data
    nr_results = 2**levels(data)
    # add an empty list for each result, so we can append the characters later
    for _ in range(nr_results):
        results.append([])

    # iterate through variants and add each variant to the prepared result
    # lists
    for variants in data:
        cycle = itertools.cycle(variants)
        for result in results:
            result.append(next(cycle))

    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['C']]
    print(["".join(x) for x in expand(data)])
```

While this seems to work, it does not feel very pythonic and I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: Specifically - `["".join(s) for s in itertools.product(*data)]`

Comment: Sorry that people like to close questions prematurely..

This is how I would do it:

from itertools import product

a = [['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'D'], ['A', 'C'], ['B'], ['C']]

b = [''.join(i) for i in product(*a)]

Comment: @GiovanniFrison - Exactly what was premature about it when your solution is the exact approach mentioned in the duplicate

Comment: @Sayse it is not exactly the same..

Comment: Yes, correct, the question seems to be a duplicate. I did search for it, but missing the term "combinations" it did not show up.

Comment: The proposed solution in the linked question works well for my use case and now I feel stupid :-)